# How can I dynamically return the sums of all of the properties in an array of homogenous objects?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with this structure:

```
{
  "_id": "5bea815d2791a76283a2747a",
  "salesCategories": [
    "cake",
    "pie",
    "baklava"
  ],
  "sales": [
    {
      "hidden": true,
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T04:33:05.703Z",
      "_id": "5beba580b60f1a52755a85ec",
      "date": "2018-11-13T23:57:42.826Z",
      "salesTotals": {
        "cake": 10,
        "pie": 10,
        "baklava": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "hidden": true,
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T04:33:06.352Z",
      "_id": "5beba581b60f1a52755a85ed",
      "date": "2018-11-13T23:57:42.826Z",
      "salesTotals": {
        "cake": 10,
        "pie": 10,
        "baklava": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "hidden": false,
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T04:33:06.995Z",
      "_id": "5beba582b60f1a52755a85ee",
      "date": "2018-11-15T23:57:42.826Z",
      "salesTotals": {
        "cake": 10,
        "pie": 10,
        "baklava": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "hidden": true,
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T04:35:49.212Z",
      "_id": "5beba582b60f1a52755a85ef",
      "date": "2018-11-13T23:57:42.826Z",
      "salesTotals": {
        "cake": 10,
        "pie": 10,
        "baklava": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "hidden": true,
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T04:36:19.590Z",
      "_id": "5beba625601d1e53cabbb6d8",
      "date": "2018-11-13T23:57:42.826Z",
      "salesTotals": {
        "cake": 10,
        "pie": 10,
        "baklava": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "hidden": false,
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T04:35:42.027Z",
      "_id": "5beba643601d1e53cabbb6d9",
      "date": "2018-11-13T23:57:42.826Z",
      "salesTotals": {
        "cake": 10,
        "pie": 10,
        "baklava": 10
      }
    }
  ],
  "deposits": [],
  "name": "katie 3",
  "cogsPercentage": 0.12,
  "taxPercentage": 0.0975,
  "createdAt": "2018-11-13T07:46:37.955Z",
  "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T04:36:19.647Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

The properties of salesTotals will match the properties of salesCategories, but there could be more or less depending in the user's preference. Therefore, the approach cannot be to hardcode sums for each of the properties directly as seen here.

I'm trying to use Mongoose to obtain the totals of the properties in salesTotals for each sale category. I also want to be able to not consider objects in the sales array that have `hidden` set to `true`, or between a date range for the calculation. I've got the last two requirements figured out when using an `aggregate()`, but I have no idea how to dynamically sum all of the contents of these objects across the entire array.

Here is what I want the desired output to look like:

```
{
  "result": {
    "cake": 60,
    "pie": 60,
    "baklava": 60
  }
}
```

I am running mongo 4.0.2 and mongoose 5.12.16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main key to working with "named keys" where you don't actually know what the names of those keys are in advance is using [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) which transforms your object into "key/value" pairs as elements of an array in a way you can actually work with them. This is a modern feature of MongoDB added in later releases for MongoDB 3.4 and of course all current future versions.

There are a few approaches of varying complexity and performance.

### Modern Reducing Array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "sales": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$sales",
                "cond": { "$not": "$$this.hidden" }
              }
            },
            "in": { "$objectToArray": "$$this.salesTotals" }
          }
        },
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
      }
    }

  }},
  { "$unwind": "$sales" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$sales.k",
    "v": { "$sum": "$sales.v" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$v" } }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }}
])
```

Using [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and conversion back with [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) so that none of the code actually needs to "hardcode" the named keys that you want to accumulate on.

The [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) essentially removes the `hidden` values, and the `$map` transforms only the content you need. The [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) could be taken further, but to accumulate across documents you need [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) later anyway.

Of course if you just mean "per document" then you could tweak that [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) a lot further:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        { "_id": "$_id" },
        {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": {
                        "$filter": {
                          "input": "$sales",
                          "cond": { "$not": "$$this.hidden" }
                        }
                      },
                      "in": { "$objectToArray": "$$this.salesTotals" }
                    }
                  },
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": {
                    "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  { "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$value",
                    "as": "val",
                    "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this.k", "$$val.k" ] }
                  }},
                  [{ 
                    "k": "$$this.k",
                    "v": {
                      "$cond": {
                        "if": { "$in": [ "$$this.k", "$$value.k" ] },
                        "then": {
                          "$sum": [
                            { "$arrayElemAt": [
                              "$$value.v",
                              { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$value.k", "$$this.k" ] }
                            ]},
                            "$$this.v"
                          ]
                        },
                        "else": "$$this.v"
                      }
                    }
                  }]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Same dynamic key names, but just done per document and in this case you don't need `$unwind` at all.

### Without $reduce

Of course you can always do this type of thing fairly traditionally:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$project": { "sales": "$sales" } },
   { "$unwind": "$sales" },
   { "$match": {
     "sales.hidden": { "$ne": true }
   }},
   { "$project": {
     "sales": { "$objectToArray": "$sales.salesTotals" }
   }},
   { "$unwind": "$sales" },
   { "$group": {
     "_id": "$sales.k",
     "v": { "$sum": "$sales.v" }
   }},
   { "$group": {
     "_id": null,
     "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$v" } }
   }},
   { "$replaceRoot": {
     "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
   }}
])
```

It does not look as complex but it is hopping through a lot of stages to get to the result. So instead of [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) an [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), and instead of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) you are doing a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) for just the wanted properties.

There's no need to concatenate arrays within the documents because each `$unwind` is breaking those arrays apart.

Overall it may be simple and easy to read, but the execution overhead increases dramatically with larger collections.

Much the same applies for the "singular document" form:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$project": { "sales": "$sales" } },
   { "$unwind": "$sales" },
   { "$match": {
     "sales.hidden": { "$ne": true }
   }},
   { "$project": {
     "sales": { "$objectToArray": "$sales.salesTotals" }
   }},
   { "$unwind": "$sales" },
   { "$group": {
     "_id": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "k": "$sales.k"
     },
     "v": { "$sum": "$sales.v" }
   }},
   { "$group": {
     "_id": "$_id._id",
     "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id.k", "v": "$v" } }
   }},
   { "$replaceRoot": {
     "newRoot": {
       "$mergeObjects": [
         { "_id": "$_id" },
         { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
       ]
     }
   }}
])
```

There's only a small change there in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages at the end and of course keeping the `_id` value of the document in the end results when reconstructing the keys.

---

Of course the results are as expected being either like:

```
{ 
  "baklava" : 20,
  "pie" : 20,
  "cake" : 20
}
```

Or per document (you only supplied one):

```
{
    "_id" : "5bea815d2791a76283a2747a",
    "cake" : 20,
    "pie" : 20,
    "baklava" : 20
}
```

The one thing that the latter forms do at least show you is from a learning perspective it is a lot easier to simply add one pipeline stage at a time and see how each stage is effecting the results with the changes it is actually making.

Taking apart the initial forms can be a bit more complicated to understand, but if you take the time to look at each part you should eventually see how they all fit together.

---

### Alternate mapReduce

Though you cannot get the same performance as the aggregation framework, if you had a MongoDB prior to a late release 3.4 then you could always use `mapReduce`:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    this.sales.forEach(s => {
      if (!s.hidden)
        emit(null, s.salesTotals);
    })
  },
  function(key,values) {
    var obj = {};

    values.forEach(value =>
      Object.keys(value).forEach(k => {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
          obj[k] = 0;
        obj[k] += value[k];
      })
    )

    return obj;
  },
  { out: { inline: 1 } }
)
```

The output is a little different since mapReduce has a strict "key/value" output form:

```
    {
        "_id" : null,
        "value" : {
                "cake" : 20,
                "pie" : 20,
                "baklava" : 20
        }
    }
```

And "per document", that's just a matter of replacing the `null` in `emit()` with the current document `_id` value:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    var id = this._id;
    this.sales.forEach(s => {
      if (!s.hidden)
        emit(id, s.salesTotals);
    })
  },
  function(key,values) {
    var obj = {};

    values.forEach(value =>
      Object.keys(value).forEach(k => {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
          obj[k] = 0;
        obj[k] += value[k];
      })
    )

    return obj;
  },
  { out: { inline: 1 } }
)
```

With fairly obvious results:

```
    {
        "_id" : "5bea815d2791a76283a2747a",
        "value" : {
                "cake" : 20,
                "pie" : 20,
                "baklava" : 20
        }
    }
```

Not as fast, but a fairly simple process which again is using `Object.keys()` as the way to extract an work with the "named keys" without knowing their names.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I went with the non-reduce way since it's easier to determine what is going iteratively, should I need to modify things. You're awesome.